# Microphone not working on a Dell (Windows 8) not even with an external sound-card

Tags: windows-8, audio, sound-card, microphone

My microphone doesn't work on my Dell Inspiron 17 laptop.
The microphone is a beyerdynamic (dynamic singing) microphone.

I've tried the following things:
- Bought an external sound card (Terretec Aureon 7.1 USB).
- Bought a cable from XLR to USB.
- From analog to 3.5 mm straight in the laptop.

Nothing works! I don't think it's a driver problem either since the device (ext. sound-card) is recognized on my laptop.

Further specs:

### Laptop

8 GB RAM
Intel i7 3537U @ 2 GHZ processor
Windows 8
Dell Inspiron 17

### Microphone

Beyerdynamic TG V35d s
Also tried: Philips SBC MD650

### Operating System

Windows 8.0 Pro 64-bit

### Drivers & Hardware bought

Terretec Aureon 7.1 USB (driver: http://ftp.terratec.de/Audio/Aureon/Aureon7.1USB/Updates/TERRATEC_Aureon_7.1_USB_Drv_Setup_8.0.8.2158_Windows_8.exe)

ART XConnect (driver installed automatically).

Comment: Have you used a different microphone like a USB microphone?

Comment: No I haven't but since I have an XLR to USB cable that would be quite the same.

Comment: Not really you assume the valve is functional

Comment: Tomorrow I'll try to connect an USB microphone and see if that works!